# Novel from the 50s or 60s where Earth people colonize a planet whose inhabitants are bonded with telepathic, cat-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

Earth people colonize a planet that already has inhabitants.  Inhabitants are bonded with cat-like creatures whose paws secrete acid and who turn out to be telepathic.  Earth people, of course, kill them but, eventually they use the cats to communicate with the planet's inhabitants.  It starts out with the male main character being awakened on Earth by an alarm clock that uses increasingly bright light instead of sound.  I remember the main female character's name as being Fiona.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, any recollection of wha the cover looked like? Also - am I right in thinking [this topic on an other forum](https://www.librarything.com/topic/61853) was yours? (so that we can safely rule out the ones proposed there)

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I've been looking for this for decades and have posted about it on the LibraryThing SciFi group.  Maybe one other, I'm not sure now.  No idea on the cover.  It came from the public library, sometime in the 60s.  I remember that the Earth folks used pelts from the cat beings to protect themselves from the acid on the paws of the live creatures and that allowed them to communicate with the locals.  At the end the man & woman married each other - "By all that's holy and sacred in the universe." or something like that.

Comment: The telepathic cats made me think of Andre Norton's *Star Ka'at* series, but I'm not sure the other details fit. https://www.goodreads.com/series/120625-star-ka-at

Comment: Thanks but, no that isn't it.  And I've pretty much looked at everything Andre Norton wrote because it made me think of her books and didn't find it.